# How to access the result outside the $http.get in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

How can I access the result of the `$http.get` outside of its success callback function?

My code is

```
$http.get('http://myserver/' + $scope.myE)
        .success(function(data) 
        {
            $scope.mydata = data;

        });

alert(JSON.stringify($scope.mydata));
```

I got undefined.

Comment: You are getting `undefined` because `alert` executes before `$http.get` returns

Comment: how can I execute alert after $http.get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the promise and do your alert in the callback:

```
// define the function that does the ajax call
getmydata = function() {
    return $http.get('http://myserver/' + $scope.myE)
        .success(function(data) 
        {
            $scope.mydata = data;

        });

}


// do the ajax call
getmydata().then(function(data) {
    // stuff is now in our scope, I can alert it
    alert($scope.mydata);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var promise = $http.get('http://server/');

promise.then(function(payload) {
    alert(payload);
});
```